# DbContext in separate class library project with dependency injection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I'm currently creating a WebAPI for a school project.
Before is worked with DI but i can't seem to get it working in the current context.

for the project i'm using multiple projects for the layer where my DAL needs to get the dbContext through DI.

DbContext:

```
public FICTIEContext(DbContextOptions<FICTIEContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
        }
    }
```

startup register:

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
       services.AddDbContext<FICTIEContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database")));
    }
```

Call to the DAL Constructor:

```
public class LoginBL
{
    private LoginDAL _LoginDAL;

    public bool LoginValidation(string login, string password)
    {
        _LoginDAL = new LoginDAL(); //Gives the error. As i remember given that dependency injection works correctly it should work like this.           
        return _LoginDAL.LoginValidation(login, password); ;
    }
}
```

for my DAL i'm using a c# class library project with a class where i have a constructor which has the DbContext as parameter:

```
       private readonly FICTIEContext _Database;

    public LoginDAL(FICTIEContext database)
    {
        _Database = database;
    }
```

When using this code i can't seem to call the constructor without getting errors about not giving any parameters with the call to the DAL.

Which part am i missing withing my solution and how can i fix it.

Comment: How are you using LoginDAL - are you injecting it somewhere (controller)?

Comment: no, i only have a reference to it from another layer where i have to call it from

Comment: Can you provide the code that is calling the LoginDAL constructor.

Comment: If you inject the DAL, the code that creates the DAL instance needs to new up the DbContext as well. But do you really need inject the DAL with a DbContext? The EF implementation of the DAL could instead create an instance of the DbContext directly. A DbContext belongs to the DAL anyway.

Comment: @Innominatum added it to the post

Comment: @mm8 maybe it does, however i tried using DI to inject it into any class in the same project as the dbcontext and this resulted in the same problem of not being able to call the constructor of the class

for second answer, i thought dependency injection meant it would be saved somewhere in the background, as before i made a razor web page app which retrieved it whenever the page was opened. looks like i need to read into it a bit more

Comment: @YannicvandeKuit: Of course you need to provide an instance of `FICTIEContext` when creating an instance of a `LoginDAL` given your current implementation. That's the purpose of dependency injection. The question is whether you actually need or want dependency injection in this case. There should be no point of testing a DAL without a context anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you need to provide an instance of `FICTIEContext` when creating an instance of a `LoginDAL` given your current implementation. That's the purpose of using dependency injection.

The question is whether you actually need or want dependency injection in this case? I doubt it. There should be no point of using nor testing the DAL class without a `DbContext` anyway.

In this case you could simply let the DAL class create an instance of the `FICTIEContext` internally. You may of course also provide an overload of the constructor that accepts a context if you want to:

```
private readonly FICTIEContext _Database;

public LoginDAL()
{
    _Database = new FICTIEContext();
}

public LoginDAL(FICTIEContext database)
{
    _Database = database;
}
```

Then the consumer of the class can choose whether to supply a custom `FICTIEContext` or let the `LoginDAL` class create a default one.